# CheckBox.setText do not work (Android)

Tags: android

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(activity);
CheckBox.setText("Hello");
```

I tried to set the text after a check box as above. But it didnt show me anything. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First :** you try to set the Text using the name of the class `CheckBox` ???

it should be the instance  `checkBox` , like this :

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(activity);
checkBox.setText("Hello");
```

**Second :**

did you try to add your **checkBox** to your **Activity  Content**  like this ??

```
this.setContentView(checkBox);
```

**EDIT:** : refer [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-dialog-radio-buttons) , may be it will help you

Comment: I'm really adding it in to a "AlertDialog.Builder". Check box appears fine. But text do not appear

Comment: @dinesh707 the key part is the first comment: setText is not a static method. You need to use use it on you instantiated object (notice the small caps in `checkBox.setText("Hello");`